# Appending list from a for loop

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to populate a list with links collected from a web page.
The list is coming up with an unexpected result.
What is wrong with the code I am using?

```
def get_contact_id(self):
    wd = self.app.wd
    elements = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'edit.php?id')]")
    print(elements)
    links = []
    for i in elements:
        link = i.get_attribute('href')
        links.append(link)
        print(links)
```

I expect to get:

```
links = ['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9','//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=11','//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=13','//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=10','//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=14']
```

Instead I am getting:

```
links = ['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9']
['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9','//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=10']
['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=10', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=11']
['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=10', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=11', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=13']
['//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=9', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=10', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=11', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=13', '//192.168.1.22:8080/addressbook/edit.php?id=14']
```

Comment: Is that just the result of the `print()` in the loop? or is it really what is in the `links` list?

Comment: You need to put that last print outside of the for loop. You are printing `links` each time you append a link to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print `links` outside of for loop.

```
def get_contact_id(self):
    wd = self.app.wd
    elements = wd.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'edit.php?id')]")
    print(elements)
    links = []
    for i in elements:
        link = i.get_attribute('href')
        links.append(link)
    print(links)
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helped me!